# Handing subscr_failed in PayPal IPN

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

hope somebody can help! I can't seen to get this code to work for updating a row in the database when a users subscription payment is refused/failed.

```
$payer_email_ipn =$_POST['payer_email'];
// failed subscription payment
if ($_POST['txn_type'] == 'subscr_failed') {
    $sql = "UPDATE ipn_testing SET account_status='0' WHERE email='$payer_email_ipn'";
    if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
        error_log(mysql_error());
        exit(0);
    }
    mail('amdin@mydomain.co.uk','IPN Notification: Subscription failed','Subscription failed for '.$payer_email_ipn);
    exit(0);
}
```

I guessed it would be similar to the code where I set the account_status to 1 when they have paid, which works just fine! But this, for whatever reason does not work! :( (code for successful payment is below)

```
$sql = "UPDATE ipn_testing SET account_status='1' WHERE email='$payer_email_ipn'";    
if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    error_log(mysql_error());
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are entering that code block? Eyeballing what you have makes sense, so I would put an errorlog just after the // failed comment to see what the value of $_POST['txn_type'] is.